# How do I populate source packages using grunt-debian-package?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, debian, packaging

I use `NodeJS` and `grunt` + `grunt-debian-package` to build `.deb` files, which works fine for creating the deployment file `foo_v.v.v_all.deb`.
I also want to distribute the plain and un-uglified source files in debian source packages (foo_v.v.v.tar.xz) but that file is rather empty.

What do I have to do to populate the source file correctly?

**My environment:**
Current dir: `/home/dev/src/foo`
Relevant parts of my `Grunt.js`

```
debian_package: {
  options: {
    maintainer: {
      name: "xxx",
      email: "xxx"
    },
    prefix: "",
    name: "foo",
    postfix: "",
    short_description: "xxx",
    long_description: "xxx",
    version: "<%=pkg.version%>",
    preinst: {
      src: "scripts/preinst",
    },
    postinst: {
      src: "scripts/postinst",
    },
    postrm: {
      src: "scripts/postrm",
    },
    prerm: {
      src: "scripts/prerm",
    },
    dependencies: "xxx",
    replaces: "xxx",
    conflicts: "xxx"
  },
  deploy: {
    files: [{
      expand: true, // enable dynamic expansion
      cwd: 'dist', // src matches are relative to this path
      src: ['**'],
      dest: '/usr/lib/foo'
    }, {
      src: "scripts/foo",
      dest: "/etc/init.d/foo"
    }, {
      src: 'root-ca.conf',
      dest: '/usr/lib/foo/root-ca.conf'
    }]

  }
}
// ----- snip -----
grunt.registerTask('package', ['debian_package']);
```

Commands that have executed correctly:

```
grunt build
grunt package
```

Result of checking the files:

```
ll tmp/
-rw-r--r--  1 dev dev 22758744 Sep 16 00:10 foo_0.1.63_all.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 dev dev      608 Sep 16 00:10 foo_0.1.63.dsc
-rw-r--r--  1 dev dev     1400 Sep 16 00:10 foo_0.1.63_i386.changes
-rw-r--r--  1 dev dev    76288 Sep 16 00:10 foo_0.1.63.tar.xz

tar -tJf tmp/foo_0.1.63.tar.xz
packaging/
packaging/debian/
packaging/debian/postinst
packaging/debian/compat
packaging/debian/postrm
packaging/debian/preinst
packaging/debian/dirs
packaging/debian/source/
packaging/debian/source/format
packaging/debian/changelog
packaging/debian/prerm
packaging/debian/copyright
packaging/debian/links
packaging/debian/control
packaging/debian/rules
packaging/Makefile
```

I want to have all files within the dir `/home/dev/src/foo/app` being contained in the file `tmp/foo_0.1.63.tar.xz`

What do I have to do for this? Should I update the `Makefile`? If yes: How?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it. I had to update the Gruntfile.js correctly.

First I defined the target directory in the `config` section:

```
 grunt.initConfig({
     config: {
         // [...]
         src_pkg: 'node_modules/grunt-debian-package/packaging
  },
```

Then I added a section for the source code within the `copy` task, separating own source code from node_modules:

```
    copy: {
    // [...]
        src_pkg: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                dest: '<%= config.src_pkg %>',
                src: [
                    '**',
                    '!**/tmp/**',
                    '!**/.tmp/**',
                    '!**/dist/**',
                    '!**/.git/**',
                    '!**/node_modules/**', // node_modules will be copied separately
                ]
            }]
        },
        src_pkg_modules: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'node_modules',
                dest: '<%= config.src_pkg %>/node_modules',
                src: [
                    // list all node_modules you want to copy also here
                ]
            }]
        },
     },
```

Later register the task (here called `package`):

```
grunt.registerTask('package', [
    'copy:src_pkg', 
    'copy:src_pkg_modules', 
    'debian_package']);
```

On the command line initiate the packaging by calling

```
grunt package
```

... and within `./tmp` you fill find the complete tarball (look at the size!):

```
ll tmp/
-rw-r--r--  1 dev dev 22678070 Okt  6 22:09 foo_0.1.78_all.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 dev dev      617 Okt  6 22:07 foo_0.1.78.dsc
-rw-r--r--  1 dev dev     1408 Okt  6 22:09 foo_0.1.78_i386.changes
-rw-r--r--  1 dev dev 38541304 Okt  6 22:07 foo_0.1.78.tar.xz
```

Answer (score 0):

In Debian packaging, the contents of the `tar.xz` (known as the "orig tarball") are fixed prior to package building starts. As grunt appears to be generating this tarball, you will likely need to find—or add—an option to grunt to include the actual source in). It's curious it does not by default, given it *is* the source tarball.

Another solution that's used with Debian itself would be to also create a `foo-source_0.1.63_all.deb` package that contains the source.

(Yes, you may be able to screw with the `tar.xz` *during* the build process, but that's not only unspeakably ugly, it's likely to break various checksums)